# how to save line breaks in code tag on sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, tinymce, syntax-highlighting

I've used asp.net mvc to create my site and I added the tinymce editor to the admin page (so that admin users can enter their code content).

Tinymce works fine and I added a Syntax Highlighter to it (prismjs).

When I enter some example code to tinymce using Syntax Highlighter and save it to the sql server, line breaks in the example code that is entered are ignored.

For example, I enter the following code into tinymce:

```
public static void Main()
{
     Console.WriteLine("Hello Worlds");
}
```

After saving it to sql Server and displaying it on another page :

```
public static void Main(){Console.WriteLine("Hello Worlds");}
```

see this picture =>[Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvDRx.jpg)

The problem is that line break are not stored in the sql server. Can anyone help me?

My model class:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace School.Areas.Admin.Models.Post
{
    public class PostModel
    {
        public PostModel()
        {
            AvalableCommentStatus = new List<SelectListItem>();
            AddPicModel = new AddPictureModel();
            PostTagList = new List<Tag>();
            DownloadFileList = new List<DownloadFileViewModel>();
            PostCategoryList = new List<PostCategoryModel>();
        }
        public long Id { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "عنوان :")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "عنوان مطلب را وارد کنید")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "خلاصه :")]
        public string Summary { get; set; }

        //my rich editor
        [AllowHtml]
        [UIHint("RichEditor")]
        [Display(Name = "محتوا :")]
        public string Content { get; set; }

        public int CountOfComment { get; set; }
        public int CountOfViewer { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "وضعیت دیدگاه ها :")]
        public CommentStatus CommentStatus { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "فایل ضمیمه :")]
        public bool HasDownloadFile { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "حجم فایل ها :")]
        public string DownloadFileSize { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "ترتیب نمایش :")]
        [UIHint("Int32")]
        public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "انتشار :")]
        public bool IsPublished { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "نمایش در صفحه اصلی :")]
        public bool ShowOnHomePage { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
        public string CreatePersianDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastModifiedDate { get; set; }
        public string ImageAddress { get; set; }
        public int CountOfPendingComment { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string AliasName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "برچسب ها :")]
        public string Tag { get; set; }
        //
        public List<SelectListItem> AvalableCommentStatus { get; set; }
        public List<PostCategoryModel> PostCategoryList { get; set; }
        public AddPictureModel AddPicModel { get; set; }
        public List<Tag> PostTagList { get; set; }
        public List<DownloadFileViewModel> DownloadFileList { get; set; }
        public class AddPictureModel
        {
            public long Id { get; set; }
            [Display(Name = "تصویر :")]
            [UIHint("Picture")]
            public long PictureId { get; set; }
            public long PostId { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            [Display(Name = "ترتیب نمایش :")]
            [UIHint("Int32Nullable")]
            public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }

        }
        public class DownloadFileViewModel
        {
            public string Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Link { get; set; }
            public long PostId { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try saving it within a HTML <pre> Tag?

Comment: The line breaks **are** stored in sqlserver. Your issue is related to styling the html in the view (and you have not bothered to show the  relevant code)

Comment: Line breaks are not stored in sql server. i check it now. Because i use [AllowHtml] attribute in model. and view model binding in mvc remove line breaks

Comment: It **does not** remove the line breaks! Read the value back in to view and put it into `<div style="white-space:pre-line;">@Model.Content</div>` and you will see it correctly displayed with line breaks.